# react-navigation Drawer lock dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How to lock the drawer dynamically ? I have a modal use from [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox). When I open up the modal, I  call this `this.refs.modal.open();` and locked the drawer. I only know that `drawerLockMode` can set in `navigationOptions`. But modal is not a screen in `DrawerNavigator`

```
const MainDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Event: { screen: EventScreen },
    Wallet: { screen: WalletScreen},
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen},
    Contact: { screen: MemberContactScreen},
    Reward: { 
      screen: MemberRewardScreen,
      navigationOptions:{
        drawerLockMode :'locked-closed'
      }},
},{
  contentComponent: props => <DrawerScreen {...props} />
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### I used the following code

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
drawerLockMode: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.drawerLockMode : undefined});
```

### For hiding the navigation drawer used this code on condition called this.

```
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ 
    drawerLockMode: locked-closed });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of [redux](https://redux.js.org/), here are the steps.

step 1: Create the reducer for drawer keep a flag in its state which we will be using to dynamically lock the drawer. 
step 2:subscribe to drawer's reducer and bind 'drawerLockMode' to that flag.
step 3: just dispatch the action from anywhere to lock the drawer.

here is the code

Your drawer component

```
class Drawer extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {drawerLockMode:this.props.drawerLockMode};
      }

    render() {
      const options = {
        //   initialRouteName: 'LandingPage',
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: SideMenu,
        drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        gesturesEnabled: false
      };
        const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, options);
      return (
        <Drawer
        screenProps={{drawerLockMode:this.props.drawerLockMode}}
        />
      );
    }
  }
function mapStatetoProps(state)
{
    return {
        drawerLockMode:state.draweReducer.drawerLockMode
    }
}
export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(Drawer);


export default function reducer(state = {drawerLockMode:'unlocked'}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case 'DRAWER_LOCK':
      return Object.assign({},state,{drawerLockMode:'locked-closed'});
    case 'DRAWER_OPEN':
    return Object.assign({},state,{drawerLockMode:'unlocked'});
  default:
    return state
}
```

}

now use

this.props.dispatch({type:'DRAWER_OPEN'});

this.props.dispatch({type:'DRAWER_CLOSE'});
to lock the drawer dynamically

Comment: This seems to cause the drawer navigator to refresh it's content hence refreshing the whole app